# How do I override plugin phtml file added by XML?

Tags: magento2, template

I have the MageFan Awesome Blog plugin for my Magento 2 instance. I've managed to override the recent posts template by adding my own BlogOverride plugin to my vendor.

Now I am trying to override the `relatedposts.phtml` file with my own code and I thought I did it the right way but nothing happened.

I first copied the file

> vendor/magefan/module-blog/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/relatedposts.phtml

to

> app/code/Company/BlogOverride/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/relatedposts.phtml

and changed the code to how I'd like it.

I then did a `grep` for the `relatedposts.phtml` file to see which XML file calls it, and it led me here:

> vendor/magefan/module-blog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

I copied it to

> app/code/Company/BlogOverride/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

where my code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content.aside">
            <block class="Magefan\Blog\Block\Catalog\Product\RelatedPosts"
                   name="product.info.blog.relatedposts"
                   as="relatedposts"
                   before='-'
                   template="Company_BlogOverride::catalog/product/relatedposts.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I then ran:

```
$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade
$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
$ php bin/magento cache:flush
```

and nothing changed, it's still using the default `relatedposts.phtml` file. How can I override files created by external plugins?

**Edit**: I've tried the below suggested answer to no avail:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance dc" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="content.aside">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Company_BlogOverride::catalog/product/relatedposts.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to add it via the **theme** - not via a plugin.

I made this directory in my theme:

> app/design/frontend/Company/default/Magefan_Blog/templates/catalog/product

where my `relatedposts.phtml` file now lives.

Refresh the page and huzzah! It works. I double checked by `rm -rf app/code/Company` and refreshing the page - my custom template still takes affect.

I think how Magento2 works in terms of the order of what it looks at, goes

> Core -> Plugins -> Themes

So the correct place to override Plugins is the next step up - themes.

Create a folder inside your theme entitled `PluginVendor_PluginName` and override like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow below code

add below code in your `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance dc" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="content.aside">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Company_BlogOverride::catalog/product/relatedposts.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

Run below commands

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: didn't seem to take affect :/